# Very hard sorting algorithm problem - O(n) time - Time complextiy

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

Since the problem is long i can not describe it at title.

Imagine that we have 2 unsorted integer arrays. Both array lenght is n and they are containing interegers between 0 - n^765 (n power 765 maximum) .

I want to compare both arrays and find out whether they contain any same integer value or not with in O(n) time complexity.

no duplicates are possible in the same array

Any help and idea is appreciated.

Comment: n^765? Thats a great number...

Comment: yes. but do not stuck on numbers. i need the logic. the problem here is of course memory. otherwise there are too many memory consuming O(n) sorting algorithms.

Comment: 2 arrays can fit into memory - but 3 can't?

Comment: There are no array count limitation. but array sizes are very important. array lenght can not be equal to the biggest number.

Comment: Are duplicates possible within each of the arrays?

Comment: no duplicates are possible. so all values in one array are different

Comment: If the arrays have length n and the largest number is n^765 then an O(1) algorithm is (probably) sufficient: the likelihood that the 2 arrays contain the same number is vanishingly close to 0 for any n>1.

Comment: High Performance Mark i have to develop an algorithm which is logical for this problem. maybe you are right but this is not an answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By assuming multiplication and division is O(1):

Think about numbers, you can write them as:

**Number(i) = A0 * n^765 + A1 * n^764 + .... + A764 * n + A765.**

for coding number to this format, you should just do Number / n^i, Number % n^i, if you precompute, n^1, n^2, n^3, ... it can be done in O(n * 765)=> O(n) for all numbers. precomputation of n^i, can be done in O(i) since `i` at most is 765 it's O(1) for all items.

Now you can write Numbers(i) as array: Nembers(i) = (A0, A1, ..., A765) and know you can radix sort items :

first compare all A765, then ...., All of Ai's are in the range 0..n so for comparing Ai's you can use [Counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) (Counting sort is O(n)), so your radix sort is O(n * 765) which is O(n).

After radix sort you have two sorted array and you can simply find one similar item in O(n) or use [merge algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm) (like merge sort) to find most possible similarity (not just one).

for generalization if the size of input items is O(n^C) it can be sorted in O(n) (C is fix number). but because the overhead of this way of sortings are big, prefer to using quicksort and similar algorithms. Simple sample of this question can be found in [Introduction to Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) book, which asks if the numbers are in range (0..n^2) how to sort them in O(n).

**Edit:** for clarifying how you can find similar items in 2-sorted lists:

You have 2 sorted list, for example in merge sort how do you can merge two sorted list to one list? you will move from start of list 1, and list 2, and move your head pointer of list1 while head(list(1)) > head(list(2)), and after that do this for list2 and ..., so if there is a similar item your algorithm will stop (before reach the end of lists), or in the end of two lists your algorithm will stop.

it's as easy as bellow:

```
public int FindSimilarityInSortedLists(List<int> list1, List<int> list2)
{
   int i = 0;
   int j = 0;


   while (i < list1.Count && j < list2.Count)
   {
      if (list1[i] == list2[j])
         return list1[i];

      if (list1[i] < list2[j])
         i++;
      else
         j++;    
   }
   return -1; // not found
}
```

Comment: this is the most logical answer. but numbers are not power of n. numbers are between 0 and n^765. for example a number can be n^765-1 or n^454-66 . at first i also thought similiar way to yours . but since numbers are not always power of n it fails.

Comment: @PokemonCraft, I didn't said that numbers are pow of `n` I said you can write each number in "A0 * n^765 + A1 * n^764 + .... + A764 * n + A765" format, for example for n^765 -1 you have : A0 = 1, A765 = -1, Ai = 0 for others, or for n^454-66 you have A310 = 1, A0 = -66, Ai = 0 for others.

Comment: i did not understand how will i check whether they contain same value or not after sorting the way you suggested without increasing O(n) time complexity.

Answer (score 6):

What you want is impossible. Each element will be stored in up to log(n^765) bits, which is O(log n). So simply reading the contents of both arrays will take O(n*logn).

If you have a constant upper bound on the value of each element, You can solve this in O(n) average time by storing the elements of one array in a hash table, and then checking if the elements of the other array are contained in it.

**Edit**:

The solution you may be looking for is to use [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) to sort your data, after which you can easily check for duplicate elements. You would look at your numbers in base n, and do 765 passes over your data. Each pass would use a bucket sort or counting sort to sort by a single digit (in base n). This process would take O(n) time in the worst case (assuming a constant upper bound on element size). Note that I doubt anyone would ever choose this over a hash table in practice.

Comment: it can be done with hashing method but i also need to have that hashing method. not just saying using hashing. so i have to explain what kind of hashing is used.

Comment: do not care about bit size. i need the logic.

Comment: @PokemonCraft: You can use pretty much any kind of hash table you want. Its size should be around 2*n. To save space, you can store pointers to the values in the hash table instead of the values themselves.

Comment: As for your second comment: maybe you don't care about bit size, but bit size means that O(n) is impossible for the problem you described.

Comment: @interjay, as you wrote in your first paragraph every iteration on a list of numbers within 0..n of size n takes O(nlog(n)), you changed the world :) so finding max item in the list of size n, and numbers within 0..n is O(nlog(n)) :) (n^765 can be coded in 765log(n) and n can be coded in log(n)), the main part of your false conclusion is there is no need to iterate over all bits. comparing items takes O(1)

Comment: @interjay bit size is not important. as i said the logic is important for me atm. also just saying you can use hash table is not solving my problem. i have to write a hashing algorithm which will hash these numbers: number count is 2n and min number is 0 and max number is n^x

Answer (score 1):

If memory was unlimited you could simply create a hashtable with the integers as keys and the values the number of times they are found.  Then to do your "fast" look up you simple query for an integer, discover if its contained within the hash table, and if found check that the value is 1 or 2.  That would take O(n) to load and O(1) to query.

Comment: @PokemonCraft: what are exactly your memory limitations? Certainly you can use O(n) memory, no?

Comment: well actually there are no memory limitations. but the array size can not be biggest number in the given arrays . for example let the biggest number is 76^534 . the array size that we are going to use can not be equal to this number. because there are so many O(n) sorting algorithms with this way working.

Comment: @PokemonCraft hashtables don't need to have space every possible item, just enough space so that items don't collide very often.  A hash table of size 2-3 times bigger than n should be more than sufficient and still far less than n^765.

Comment: @MerickOWA  just saying hashing would solve your problem do not help me. i already know using hash would solve this problem. but i have to code an hashing algorith for numbers count : 2n and numbers are between 0- n^x . x is not important. the important thing is logic.

Comment: @PokemonCraft a hash algorithms job is to go from large number range (0 - n^x) to small number range (0 - 2n).  Is help with a hash algorithm what you need?

Comment: @MerickOWA  yes a propoer hash algorithm for this question would solve my problem. but there should not be any collision.

Comment: @PokemonCraft the only way to guarantee that is to have knowledge prior to implementation of what those numbers will be.  If there's any variation in those lists (i.e. they are not static for all runs) eventually you will get a collision.

Comment: wheaties you do not have any idea about numbers. so they can change at every run

Comment: @PokemonCraft I don't completely understand your comment but... What I'm saying is that the input, i.e. the list of numbers, must be static in nature to guarantee that you're never going to get a collision.  Otherwise it's impossible to guarantee that you're never going to be a collision.

Comment: in that case that is not a solution for me. because i have to guarantee no collision at all to determine whether there are any same value or not in the given arrays

Answer (score -1):

I do not think you can do it O(n).
You should check n values whether they are in the other array. This means you have n comparing operations at least if the other array has just 1 element. But as you have n element it the other array as well, you can do it just O(n*n)

Comment: You can do membership checks in ~O(1) time. Look up hash tables.

Comment: well you can do it with O(n) time complexity for sure since it is asked from me to achive this. Also hash table is a good way but what kind of hash algorithm i can use. i have to also have an idea about hash algorithm . because it is also asked. hash algorithm for sure would solve the problem but it can not be a black box :)

Comment: @Pokemon: "well you can do it with O(n) time complexity for sure since it is asked from me to achive this" Your reasoning is deeply flawed here. You are fortunate not having had the experience of dealing with professors who have zero clue what they are talking about.

Comment: Do not forget the cost of building a hash table

Comment: @ Mehrdad Afshari  maybe it is unfortunate that you can not solve this kind of problem ^^. well this is possible with O(n) time complexity without having biggest number sized array. and i have to figure it out :)

Comment: @Zoltan, in a hashtable insertion, deletion and lookup share the same basic algorithm and all have the same complexity.

Comment: if we can develop a hashing algorithm by using number of elements (2n) biggest and smallest values 0-n^x

Comment: @Pokemon: Because you know nothing about the distribution of the input (other than a maximum value), the best size for an hashtable is probably the prime nearest to N. And for the hash function, calculating the remainder of the division of the number by the table size could be good enough.

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes this hash function would fail for sure . for example my n is 100. so as you suggested i have created a hash table with 100 size. and all of these numbers would have same hash value 111 211 311 411 etc. I have to determine whether given arrays are containing same value or not with time complexity O(n) without using biggest number size array. for example bucket sort and counting sort algorithms produces result for with O(n) time. but they do require biggest number sized array.

Comment: @Pokemon: Unless you know more about the input (like say, "it will always be a number ending in ...11"), you cannot get a hash function that will not produce collisions. Even if you know something more, you may not be able to write a perfect hash function. If you know nothing about the input distribution, that hash function is as good as any other. And way easier to write.

Comment: Oh, and as I suggested the table would have size 101, :)

Comment: there should not be any collision for determining whether any same input or not. so collision produces hashing algorithms would fail.

Comment: @PokemonCraft: Sorry but all generic hashing algorithms produce collisions. If you know nothing about the input distribution then you either 1) use a hashtable as big as your input, which you said you can't; or 2) use a hash function with collisions. The one I gave works best for a uniform distribution (when no numbers have higher probabilities than others).

Comment: Martinho Fernandes well in that case that would not a be solution for me since if there are collision there is no way to determine whether there are any same value or not in O(n) time